# ReplaceWith function not working with Clone

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new to JQuery.  I am trying to use ReplaceWith and Clone to quickly restore the data in text boxes to their original state if the user clicks a Cancel button.  When the user clicks Edit, the Edit button disappear and is replaced with a Save and a Cancel button and the text boxes are enabled.  If they press Cancel, I want this to be reversed, with the original text restored if it has been changed.

I am attempting to Clone to store the div contents when the Edit button is clicked and RestoreWith to cancel changes when Cancel is clicked. Both the CloneContent and the RestoreContent functions are called as expected (all the alerts in the code below appear as expected), but nothing changes on the screen when Cancel is clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

script -

```
 var divClone;

 function CloneContent(mydiv) {
     alert('cloning');
     divClone = $(mydiv).clone(true, true);
     alert('finished cloning');
 }

 function RestoreContent(mydiv) {
     alert('restoring');
     $(mydiv).replaceWith($(divClone));
     alert('finished restoring');
     return false;
 }
```

and the asp code -

```
<asp:panel ID="pnlNames" runat="server">

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditNames" runat="server" 
        OnClientClick="CloneContent('<%=pnlNames.ClientID%>')" 
        OnCommand="lnkEdit_Click" Text="Edit" />

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdateNames" runat="server" 
        OnCommand="lnkUpdate_Click" Text="Save" Visible="false" />

    <asp:LinkButton id="lnkCancelEditNames" runat="server" 
        onclientclick="RestoreContent('<%=pnlNames.ClientID%>')" 
        Text="Cancel" Visible="false" /> 

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="50" ID="txtLastName" Enabled="false" />


</asp:panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

To restore the original data when the user clicks "Cancel" you don't need to use `Clone` and `ReplaceWith` at all.

Just save the current value on edit, and reset the field to the saved value on cancel.

Also, don't use `onclick` or similar inline event handlers when you are working with jQuery. Try to avoid element IDs, too. Use CSS classes instead. This way the same JavaScript code can be used for all the input fields on your page.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:panel ID="pnlNames" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="edit" Text="Edit" />
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="save" Text="Save" Visible="false" />
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="cancel" Text="Cancel" Visible="false" />
    <asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" ID="txtLastName" Enabled="false" />
</asp:panel>
```

Corresponding JS:

```
$(".edit").on("click", function () {
    var $textBox = $(this).parent().find(":text"),

    // hide and show buttons    
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".save").show();
    $(this).parent().find(".cancel").show();

    // save current value into jQuery data for the textbox
    $textBox.data("oldValue", $textBox.val())
});

$(".cancel").on("click", function () {
    var $textBox = $(this).parent().find(":text"),

    // hide and show buttons    
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".save").hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".edit").show();

    // restore textbox value from jQuery data
    $textBox.val( $textBox.data("oldValue") );
});

$(".save").on("click", function () {
    // hide and show buttons    
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".cancel").hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".edit").show();
});
```

Comment: Is this considered better practice?  It will be a considerably complex method for me because I have a lot of input fields of various types and some are grouped together.  The input boxes are not necessarily in the same div as the buttons.  This method assumes a particular layout I think so will break if I change the layout in the future?

Comment: @JoG The HTML layout should support the UI actions you are planning to implement in some way or another. Putting things that belong together under the same parent is one of the ways you can do that. There are other ways, too. My code was of course targeted at the example you gave, so it takes the `.parent()`. Use any of jQuery's tree traversal functions that fits your HTML layout.

Comment: @Tomalak, you, m*****f****** genius. Thank you very much. I have been struggling with this for some hours and now I found your solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Not tested yet.. but you are passing the clientID directly into jQuery? I think you need to prefix it with `#` in order to look up the element by id.

Secondly, I don't think you need to pass the div in the `$` anymore when replacing

updated code:

```
 var divClone;

 function CloneContent(mydiv) {
     alert('cloning');
     divClone = $('#' + mydiv).clone(true, true);
     alert('finished cloning');
 }

 function RestoreContent(mydiv) {
     alert('restoring');
     $('#' + mydiv).replaceWith(divClone);
     alert('finished restoring');
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.  The second alert in CloneContent no longer fires.

Comment: Oh also I did previously try no $ after the ReplaceWith, it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tomalak's answer for putting me on the right track, but I didn't want the code to be dependent on the hierarchy of the divs or the number of input elements within the editable div.  I use a classname to identify the containing div instead of "parent()".

First the html.  Testing for a two text boxes, a drop down list and a checkbox.

```
<div id="divNames" name="divNames" class="LPCEditGroup memNames">

    <a id="lnkEditNames" name="lnkEditNames" onclick="SaveDefault(this)" class="editbutton memNames" href="#/">Edit</a>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdateNames" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkUpdate_Click" Text="Save" style="display:none;" class="updatebutton memNames"/>
    <a id="lnkCancelEditNames" name="lnkCancelEditNames" onclick="RestoreDefault(this)" style="display:none" class="cancelbutton memNames" href="#/">Cancel</a>
    <br />     
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="50" ID="txtLastName" CSSClass="myinput memNames"  Enabled="false" />
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="50" ID="TextBox1" CSSClass="myinput memNames"  Enabled="false" />
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dd" CssClass="myinput memNames"      >
             <asp:ListItem Text ="One" Value="1"/>
             <asp:ListItem Text ="Two" Value="2" />
             <asp:ListItem Text ="Three" Value="3" />

         </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Checked="true"  CssClass="myinput memNames"  />
</div>
```

And the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.editbutton').click(function() {
            //remove the class name 'editbutton' from the class string which will leave us with the classname shared by the group of elements we want to edit
             var editClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('editbutton', '').replace(' ', ''); 

            var mydiv = $('div.LPCEditGroup.' + editClass).get(0);

            //replace the class name to change the panel to look selected
            $('#' + mydiv.id).attr('class', 'LPCEditGroupEditing ' + editClass);

            //get all elements sharing the edit group classname & store the default values
            $(mydiv).find('.myinput').each(function (curIdx, curO) {
                $(curO).attr('default-value', $(curO).val());
            });

            $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.editbutton').hide();
            $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.updatebutton').show();
            $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.cancelbutton').show();

            //enable everything in the panel that the edit button is in
            $('div#' + mydiv.id).find(':input').prop('disabled', false);

            return true;
        })
         $( '.cancelbutton' ).click(function() {

            //restore default for all items where edit group class name is for the current edit group

             var editClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('cancelbutton', '').replace(' ', ''); 
             var mydiv = $('div.LPCEditGroupEditing.' + editClass).get(0);


             //replace the class name to change the panel to look unselected
             $('#' + mydiv.id).attr('class', 'LPCEditGroup ' + editClass);


             $(mydiv).find('.myinput').each(function (curIdx, curO) {
                $(curO).val($(curO).attr('default-value'));
            });

             $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.editbutton').show();
             $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.updatebutton').hide();
             $('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.cancelbutton').hide();

             //disable everything in the panel that the edit button is in
             $('div#' + mydiv.id).find(':input').prop('disabled', true);

            return true;
            });
        });
```

Comment: I know it's a beginner's thing, but take my advice: Resist the urge to write obvious comments. `$('div#' + mydiv.id).find('.cancelbutton').hide();` does not need `//hide cancel button` above it. The code says that it hides the cancel button in plain English. Writing obvious comments does three things: 1) It doubles the size of the source code. 2) When reading the program, you start to read mostly the comments and gloss over the code. 3) When you change code and forget to update the comment, they become out of sync. All of these three things are bad. Drop the useless comments.

Comment: Seems so obvious now you say it :-) - I've just been following my formal IT education background which was basically 'comment everything' as part of documentation.  But I didn't study web dev which of course is different as the comments aren't stripped out on compilation.

Comment: "Comment everything" is an outdated paradigm. It might have been useful in times when people wrote assembler. Modern programming languages are expressive enough to write obvious code. If a section is obscure, break it up into separate functions. Use speaking variable/function names. I wouldn't say "comment nothing", but find a balance. Every comment you write should survive one round of "Do I *really* need this comment here?". For example, a good function name is way more useful than a comment blurb above a bad function name: It's even self-documenting everywhere you use it.